# Insert a word between two words form grep result in rhel

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to add a word to a grep result and then print it into a file

Example:

```
grep "Total number of matching entries" locked.txt >> file.txt
```

current output:

```
#Total number of matching entries: 10
```

expected output:

```
#Total number of matching entries: Locked=10
```

Used the following command:

```
grep "Total number of matching entries" | sed '/:/i Terminated=' > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sed should do it as reg ex can be fed to it too. Does this work for you?

```
sed -n 's/Total number of matching entries: /&Locked=/p' locked.txt >> file.txt
```

Comment: This works! according to my requirement :) needed something like this. Can you please tell why was -n and /p used?

Comment: n is for suppressing the output as sed by default outputs the contents in the file. p is for print.  You can read a bit more in sed documentation :)

Comment: You can also use `&` for the replacement text. That is: `sed -n 's/Total number of matching entries: /&Locked=/p' locked.txt >> file.txt`